# Force loading of mmap'ed pages

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I have mapped a file into memory using `mmap`. Now I would like to ensure that there will be no page faults when accessing this memory, i.e. I want to force the system to actually read the data from the harddisk and store it in RAM. I believe 
that once the data is there, I can prevent swapping with `mlockall`. But what is the *proper* way to get the system to load the data?

I could obviously just do dummy reads of all the pages, but this seems like an ugly hack. Also, I don't want to worry about the compiler being too smart and optimizing away the dummy reads.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  If you want to do dummy reads, just do them through a `volatile` pointer, that will prevent the compiler from optimizing them away.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I need real-time performance. volatile would probably work, but the point of my question is really how to *avoid* dummy reads.

Comment: Why do you think `mlock()`/`mlockall()` wouldn't work? Guaranteeing that the affected pages are in RAM is exactly what it's for.

Comment: BTW, it's worth generally noting that volatile gets interesting with pointers - there are volatile pointers, and there are pointers to volatiles.

Comment: @Celada: They ensure that the pages won't be *swapped out*, but they don't ensure that they will be *read in*.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that's not how I read the manpage. I upgraded my comment to an answer.

Comment: Assuming you aren't going to be writing to the file, I wonder if your goal is perhaps defeating most of the purpose of mmap()?  You seem to want to block the flexibility which mmap() gives the system over the approach of allocating memory and explicitly reading the file into it.  What do you see as the residual value of the mmap() approach after you accomplish your goal?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I think `mmap` is much more concise and better expresses my intention than using `malloc` and a for loop with explicit `read` calls. Also, at some later point I do want to write to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `MAP_POPULATE`.

Comment: That's indeed what I want, thanks! It's a bit annoying that it conflicts with `MAP_SHARED` though.

Comment: @Nikratio: Where do you see that they conflict?

Comment: mmap manpage: "MAP_POPULATE is only supported for private mappings since Linux 2.6.23."

Comment: @Nikratio: ["Am I right to understand that with this patch MAP_POPULATE now **also** works with MAP_PRIVATE mappings?"](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0805.0/1921.html) (emphasis mine)

Comment: of course, that makes a lot more sense, so that's probably what's meant.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you think `mlock()` or `mlockall()` wouldn't work? Guaranteeing that the affected pages are in RAM is exactly what its purpose is. Quoting from the manpage:

> All pages that contain a part of the specified address range are guaranteed to be resident in RAM when the call returns successfully; the pages are guaranteed to stay in  RAM  until later unlocked.

You can use other methods like `madvise()` to *ask* for the pages to be loaded into RAM but it's not guaranteed the kernel will comply with that and it's not guaranteed that they will stay in RAM even if the kernel does bring them in. I believe `mmap(MAP_POPULATE)` also doesn't guarantee that the pages will stay in RAM.